# Automatically deleting files that contain a specific content

Tags: terminal, finder, file, macos

I would like to make use of the command that looks for a specific phrase in a file:

```
grep -lr "text to find" *
```

provided [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20001105214242629) and delete all of the found files. How can I generate the relevant terminal command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete them without further ado, use

```
rm $(grep -lr "text to find" *)
```

The `$(..)` runs the command within the parenthesis and uses its output as arguments for `rm`.