# Delete all files with regex in name

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, automation

I wish to delete all files in a directory whose name *contains* the regex:  `[0-9]+`

Where I at least intend  `[0-9]+` to match with a space followed by one or more digits, with any leading or trailing text.

I cannot get the following to work:

- [Automatically deleting files that contain a specific content](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218160/automatically-deleting-files-that-contain-a-specific-content)
- [Delete files with regular expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/delete-files-in-a-directory-that-match-a-regexp-using-a-mac-terminal)
- [How to delete files containing a character or number/digit in their filename on Linux or Unix](https://superuser.com/questions/392872/delete-files-with-regular-expression)
- [Delete files in a directory that match a regexp, using a Mac terminal](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-delete-files-containing-character-numberdigit/)

Please, how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Excellent research - thanks for showing what you have considered. When you say you can not get the following to work, what does that look like? (It’s hard to guess what progress you make or if deleting any file is the main issue and not crafting a regular expression.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I will bare that in mind when asking questions going forward.  Apologies for missing this prior to receiving the answer below. Often, my issue was unknown. The command would complete, but fail to execute as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `find -E . -type f -regex ".* [0-9]+.*" -print` prints the files matching your description. (Compared to the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/delete-files-in-a-directory-that-match-a-regexp-using-a-mac-terminal, I've added "-E" — see the man page for `find`.) So then, for example

```
find -E . -type f -regex ".* [0-9]+.*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

deletes the matching files.

Comment: Fantastic - saved me hours. Thank you very much!